# Как спарсить определенный товар с сайта, при этом не зная точных наименований?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

У меня есть excel файл с 2-мя таблицами: в первой таблице название товара, а во второй цена.
Мне надо спарсить с сайтов только тот товар, который есть в таблице, **но** название товара на разных сайтах могут отличаться, есть предположение, что некоторые слова, все же, будут схожи с названиями из excel файла.
Может, кто-то сталкивался с такими задачами, может, кто какой совет дать?
Парсер на питоне.

Comment: А ссылки на товары у вас есть?

Comment: Да, есть конечно

Comment: Тогда можно сканировать страницу находить индекс обозначение  рубля и отнимать один тем самым находить цену на сайте! Можно ещё через относительный  xpath  путь !

Comment: начните с 
Beautiful Soup — библиотека для синтаксического разбора файлов HTML/XML.
Requests – библиотека для получения, данных из интернета. Позволяет создавать запросы к сайтам и получать ответы с запрошенными данными.

Comment: Excel файл можно прочитать в pandas, затем работать с dataframe. На сайтах, в большинстве случаев, есть поиск, можно наименования "*вбивать туда*", точнее использовать REST запрос для поиска, затем по выданным наименованиям смотреть что подходит, а что нет. Методом проб и ошибок.

Answer (score 1):

Расскажу на примере товаров, в которых я разбираюсь — трубопроводная арматура.

1. Действительно важно понимать по какой причине и насколько может отличаться название товаров от ваших данных. Как правило это зависит от сферы применения, общепринятых стандартов или обычаев, ну и конечно от источника ваших данных.
   Например, если мы говорим о трубопроводной арматуре, на разных сайтах по-разному:

   - может отличаться написание диаметра, DN50 или Ду50 либо ⌀50;
   - отличается написание характеристики стали, нерж/нержавеющая/12Х18Н10Т
   - да и сам порядок слов в названии отличается почти всегда:
     *"Задвижка Tecofi VG6400-00 шиберная ножевая со штурвалом и выдвижным штоком из нержавеющей стали"* или то же изделие - "ЗАДВИЖКА ШИБЕРНАЯ НЕРЖ ОДНОСТОРОННЯЯ МЕЖФЛ VG6400-00 СО ШТУРВАЛОМ TECOFI"
2. Если вы парсите товар технически более сложный, чем товары из продуктового супермаркета, то на первое место выходят характеристики товара, а не его название. Как вы могли заметить, в п.1 в названии задвижек не фигурирует диаметр, а это самый важный параметр, цена по диаметрам отличается в разы.

С учетом вышесказанного я бы предложил такое решение (*будем искать Чугунную задвижку 30ч39р с обрезиненным клином DN50 PN16*):

1. Парсим страницу каталога на сайте с помощью `Beautiful Soup` и библиотеки `requests`, предварительно определив какой элемент и с каким идентификатором отвечает за название товаров, а также извлекаем текстовую составляющую:

   ```py
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import requests

   url = 'https://www.santech.ru/catalog/317/319/'

   page = requests.get(url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

   products = [x.text for x in soup.findAll('span', class_='products__name')]
   ```
2. Далее нужно каким-то образом сравнить название с тем, что мы добыли. Простое сравнение строк или даже отдельных слов, не даст хорошего результата, поэтому можно использовать [Расстояние Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0), чтобы найти что-то похожее на наше наименование:

   ```py
   def distance(reference, test):
       m = len(reference)
       n = len(test)

       # Создаем словари для подсчета частоты слов в строках
       freq1 = {}
       freq2 = {}

       # Заполняем словарь freq1 для исходной строки
       for word in reference.split():
           freq1[word] = freq1.get(word, 0) + 1

       # Заполняем словарь freq2 для тестируемой строки
       for word in test.split():
           freq2[word] = freq2.get(word, 0) + 1

       # Создаем матрицу размером (m+1) x (n+1) и заполняем ее значениями от 0 до m и от 0 до n
       dp = [[0] * (n + 1) for x in range(m + 1)]
       for i in range(m + 1):
           dp[i][0] = i
       for j in range(n + 1):
           dp[0][j] = j

       # Заполняем матрицу построчно
       for i in range(1, m + 1):
           for j in range(1, n + 1):
               if reference[i - 1] == test[j - 1]:
                   dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j - 1]
               else:
                   delete_cost = dp[i - 1][j] + 1
                   insert_cost = dp[i][j - 1] + 1
                   replace_cost = dp[i - 1][j - 1] + 1
                   dp[i][j] = min(delete_cost, insert_cost, replace_cost)

       return dp[m][n]
   ```
3. Применяем функцию. Она будет возвращать число, наименьший результат будет являтся предполагаемым решением, если результат равен 0 - строки равны:

   ```py
   reference = "Чугунная задвижка 30ч39р с обрезиненным клином DN50 PN16"
   products_score = [distance(reference, x) for x in products]

   ##Сортируем наименования по полученным значениям
   combined_list = list(zip(products, products_score))

   sorted_list = sorted(combined_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
   print(sorted_list) 
   #>>>
   [('Задвижка чугун 30ч39р МЗВ обрезиненный клин фл ЛМЗ', 30),
    ('Задвижка чугун 30ч39р МЗВ обрезиненный клин фл ЛМЗ', 30),
    ('Задвижка чугун 30ч939р аналог МЗВ обрезиненный клин фл Китай', 39),
    ('Задвижка чугун 30ч539р аналог МЗВ обрезиненный клин фл Китай', 39), ('Задвижка чугун 30ч939р аналог МЗВ обрезиненный клин фл Benarmo', 40),
    ('Задвижка чугун 111D аналог МЗВ обрезиненный клин фл Zetkama', 40),
    ('Задвижка чугун VOC4241C аналог МЗВ обрезиненный клин фл Tecofi', 42),
    ('Задвижка чугун VOC4241CM аналог МЗВ обрезиненный клин фл Tecofi', 42),
    ('Задвижка чугун VOC4251C аналог МЗВ обрезиненный клин фл Tecofi', 42),
    ('Задвижка чугун VOC4241C аналог МЗВ обрезиненный клин фл Tecofi', 42),
    ('Задвижка чугун 30ч906бр фл ЛМЗ', 43),
    …]
   ```
4. Несмотря на то, что нужная задвижка(название ссылки на нужную задвижку) была найдена, результаты не утешительны и как минимум нужны серьезные доработки:

   - в названиях нет характеристик диаметра, поэтому необходимо уже дальше парсить страницы товаров и их характеристики, тем более их оказалось даже две;
   - если бы мы искали "Чугунную задвижку 30ч939р с обрезиненным клином" мы бы ее не нашли, поэтому необходимо выявлять какие-то ключевые храктеристики и за их полное совпадение вычитать какие-то баллы или вовсе стразу сказать, что это то, что нам нужно;
   - если бы мы нашли "Чугунную задвижку 30ч939р с обрезиненным клином", то не факт, что бы нам понравилось то, что она китайская.

Поэтому задача эта не слишком простая. Но вы также можете посмотреть в сторону использования какого-либо поискового движка или библиотеки, которые используются для создания поиска на сайтах, тем самым вы с большей вероятностью можете найти нужный товар, даже несмотря на то, что названия могут отличаться от ваших данных.
Для сравнения строк также можно использовать библиотеку `difflib`.

Comment: Под Левенштейна есть очень удобная библиотека [thefuzz](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/fuzzy-string-python) и, как вы правильно упомянули, difflib тоже прекрасен.